# Windows 10 freezes after login (dual boot with Linux)

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

Here is what I did: I use linux installed on my SSD. Lately I've decided to install windows 7 on another separated HDD (non-ssd) and upgrade it to windows 10.
So I temporary disconnected the SSD with linux installation and installed windows 7 on the other hdd which I formatted before installation. Then I upgraded windows to the latest version. Everything worked fine until I connected the SSD with linux back to my notebook. if the ssd is connected to the computer, windows always completely freezes at random time after login process (Only thing I can do is hold power button to turn of the computer).

Note that I haven't changed sata ports on which both drives was connected at the beginning of process.
I'm sure that this is not hardware issue.
Note that I tried turn off fast startup option in power options.
The SSD on which linux system is at, is formatted to `ext4`. HDD with windows system has `ntfs` filesystem.

HDD with windows installation is set up as first boot option and is connected to sda.
With this setup computer automatically boots to windows. if I want to boot to linux I have to hold ESC key before boot time and choose the SSD as boot option. (I hate this behavior but it's only thing I could think of to help windows boot properly)
This really makes me absolutely crazy! Do you have some ideas how to solve the issue?
Would it change anything if I would rollback windows 10 upgrade back to windows 7?

### UPDATE:

After @Michael's answer which unfortunately did not make any difference I spent several hours with testing the behavior. I tested the following scenario multiple times in row and it always behaved in the same way:

**HDD = hard drive with Windows 10 Pro 64bit (BUILD 10240) installed in it (not `UEFI`)**
**SSD = solid state drive with Xubuntu 14.04 64bit installed in it (not `UEFI`)**

So I started with only `HDD` connected to the computer and as expected in this state `Windows` never freeze.
Then I connected `SSD` but again booted to the `HDD` with `Windows` in it. `Windows` also doesn't freeze in this state.
I continued and restarted the computer and booted to the `SSD` with `Xubuntu` in it, after I logged in, I shut down the computer and tried to boot to `Windows` again. This time `Windows` always froze before or during login process and usually ended up with blue screen of death after while of waiting.
After this I followed up with trying to boot to `Windows` again several times.
Result was that `Windows` always froze AFTER login at random time (it didn't freeze immediately, it was running couple of minutes without an issue until it froze...) until I disconnected `SSD` then it was possible to ran `Windows` smoothly again.

Note that Windows doesn't freeze if logged in `safe mode` (at least it didn't happen to me during the time of testing).

**Conclusion:**

Linux edits something related to boot sequence every time I boot to the Linux which keeps `Windows` from booting properly after then.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that I tried turn off fast startup option in power options

Check if your Win10 drive contains a file "hiberfil.sys". If so, Win10 is still using some kind of fast startup. You can disable this by aplying the command (run in a console with administrator rights):

```
powercfg /H off
```

I had a similar problem and this helped.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Michael ! Unfortunately id did not help. See updated answer if interested.